# Filter based on specific condition in a vector

Tags: r

I have the following table and would like to filter based on the criteria below

Replicating the data first:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a","a","a","a",
                     "b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b",
                     "c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c",
                     "d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d"), value = c(0,0,1,1,2,0,0,1,
                                                                 1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,
                                                                 1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,
                                                                 0,2,2,2,2,2,2,3))
```

Now, I would like to create a condition by ID such that it meets the following condition:

1) There is an increase in value (>=1)
2) The increase in value stays the same
3) Min starting of the increase should be within the last 3 consecutive rows (basically ID:"D" does not qualify)

According to the above table, only B and C qualify

I have done the following so far but it not working for me properly especially the 3rd criteria.

```
dt1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(change = value -lag(value)) 
%>% filter(all(change %in% c(2,1,0,NA), na.rm = T))
```

Comment: What does this mean? "Min starting of the increase should be within the last 3 consecutive rows"? I ask because ID D is increasing both before and within the last 3 rows.

Comment: See example D. Even though it has an increase in value, the increase is not in the last 3 consecutive rows so it does not meet the criteria. Does that make sense?

Comment: It would, except that there is an increase in the last 3 rows

Comment: Might be best if you provided an expected output.

Comment: Right so you are talking about the change from 0 to 2 right? But in that case it does not meet criteria 2 (i.e. once there is a change it remains the same)

Comment: In ID B the increase does not occur within the last 3 rows, so why does B qualify?

Comment: I think I need to change the wording there. I meant to say that the change has to occur with at more than or equal to 3 consecutive occurrences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to group by 'ID', `filter` the groups that have only increasing adjacent elements and not any value decreasing, then filter the groups with frequency of the 'value' greater than or equal to 3 for `all` the elements

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
dt1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(cumsum(c(1, diff(value)  < 0))) == 1) %>%        
   filter(all(table(rleid(value))>=3))
# A tibble: 16 x 2
# Groups:   ID [4]
#   ID    value
#   <fct> <dbl>
# 1 b         1
# 2 b         1
# 3 b         1
# 4 b         2
# 5 b         2
# 6 b         2
# 7 b         2
# 8 b         2
# 9 c         1
#10 c         1
#11 c         1
#12 c         1
#13 c         1
#14 c         3
#15 c         3
#16 c         3
```

Comment: This actually solves it. Thank you!! First time coming across rleid function